# Google Apps Script - Google Calendar - getEvents() multiple search queries - OR logic

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to fetch all events from my google calendar that have either TERM_A or TERM_B in its event title. In other words, I am trying to use OR logic in my search query of `getEvents()` function for `CalendarApp`.

MWE:

```
function mwe(){
  var mycal = "my@emailaddress.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("June 26, 2018 00:00:00 CST"), new 
   Date("July 18, 2020 23:59:59 CST"), {search: SEARCH-FOR-TERM_A-OR-TERM_B});
  Logger.log(events);
 }
)
```

I have tried the following in place of SEARCH-FOR-TERM_A-OR-TERM_B:

- "TERM_A" | "TERM_B"
- "TERM_A | TERM_B"
- "TERM_A TERM_B"
- "'TERM_A' | 'TERM_B'"

and many such variants with zero success.

Related questions asked:

- [Same question But old post](https://support.google.com/calendar/forum/AAAAd3GaXpE4qCLHSNWMsM?hl=en)
- [Explains query format but OR operator not mentioned](https://docs.simplecalendar.io/google-calendar-search-queries/)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `or` instead of `|`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `OR` and `or` both. TERM_A returns one entry. TERM_B returns one entry. TERM_A or TERM_B returns empty output.

Comment: Tried ````+````?

Comment: Yes tried `and`, `AND`, `+`. The `+` is basically for a combination of words. It returns events where title has BOTH words.

Answer (score 2):

It may be not the best solution as it doesn't take advantage from Google search algorithm in one step, but what I've done to achieve the same thing is to use two searches and then concatenate the arrays:

```
var events = ...        
var events2 = ...
events = events.concat(events2);
```

And any other searches that you would need. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

{search: TERM_A+TERM_B}

I put the following comments in my scripts for reference:

```
 // Explanation of how the search section works (as it is NOT quite like most things Google) as part of the getEvents function:
  //    {search: 'word1'}              Search for events with word1
  //    {search: '-word1'}             Search for events without word1
  //    {search: 'word1 word2'}        Search for events with word2 ONLY
  //    {search: 'word1-word2'}        Search for events with ????
  //    {search: 'word1 -word2'}       Search for events without word2
  //    {search: 'word1+word2'}        Search for events with word1 AND word2
  //    {search: 'word1+-word2'}       Search for events with word1 AND without word2
  //    {search: '-word1+-word2'}      Search for events without word1 AND without word2 (I find this to work logically like an 'OR' statement)

var dateStart = sheet.getRange('C3').getValue();
var dateEnd = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue();
  // C3 and C4 are the col/row location for the date range

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(dateStart), new Date(dateEnd), {search: 'TERM_A+TERM_B'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 01, 2013 00:00:00 UTC"), new Date("October 01, 2020 23:59:59 UTC"), {search: 'FIRST'});
events = events.concat(cal.getEvents(new Date("January 01, 2013 00:00:00 UTC"), new Date("October 01, 2020 23:59:59 UTC"), {search: 'SECOND'}));
events = events.concat(cal.getEvents(new Date("January 01, 2013 00:00:00 UTC"), new Date("October 01, 2020 23:59:59 UTC"), {search: 'THIRD'}));
```

And it works pretty well...

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - Guess its better than nothing lol

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this thread was extremely helpful and I swiped soem ideas from here to come up with the following:

Method that supports one search term:

```
var calendarEntries=calendar.getEvents(fromDate,toDate,{search:searchTerm});
```

New method that accepts terms separated by | - variable names are a bit off because I wanted to keep searchTerm as the search string, just add | handling:

```
var calendarEntries=[];
var searchTerms=searchTerm.split("|");
for (searchKey in searchTerms){
  calendarEntries=calendarEntries.concat(calendar.getEvents(fromDate,toDate,{search:searchTerms[searchKey]}));
}
```

This seems to work well in initial testing.